# How to select only 1 row from ordered table for each ID?

Tags: sql

This is my SQL code:

```
SELECT a.ID
    , a.Date
    , a.Value
    , b.Alias
FROM NAV a
    LEFT JOIN Portfolio b ON a.ID = b.ID
ORDER BY a.ID, a.Date DESC, b.Alias, a.Value
```

It gives me a table that looks something like this:

```
| ID | Date | Value | Alias |   
|----|------|-------|-------|   
| 1  | 2021 | 300   | A     |   
| 1  | 2020 | 200   | A     |   
| 1  | 2019 | 400   | A     |   
| 2  | 2021 | 800   | B     |   
| 2  | 2020 | 700   | B     |   
| 3  | 2021 | 600   | C     |   
| 3  | 2019 | 300   | C     |   
| 3  | 2018 | 500   | C     |
```

I want to only choose the most first row for each ID. How would I go about doing that? Apologies for the basic question, am new to SQL.

Comment: Sample data is great, but you should also specify the expected result.

Comment: Hey! yeah that's the part i'm stuck on. i'm not sure how to specify i only want 1 for each ID.

Comment: Do you mean 1 _row_ for each ID? The oldest one or the newest one perhaps?

Comment: Oh yeah. 1 row for each ID. The one with the highest date.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT n.ID, n.Date, n.Value, p.Alias
FROM (SELECT n.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY Date DESC) as seqnum
      FROM NAV n
     ) n LEFT JOIN
     Portfolio p
     ON p.ID = n.ID
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY n.ID;
```

Note:

- Use *meaningful* table aliases instead of arbitrary letters.
- I doubt a `LEFT JOIN` is needed.  Are there really values of `ID` in `NAV` that are not in `Portfolio`?

Answer (score 0):

ANSI standard SQL (assuming this returns the correct results)
Call NAV table twice -
First time - get the row of interest (table aliased as c
then use that row to get the relevant a.value by joining on both c.ID and c.Date to a.ID and a.Date

```
SELECT    c.ID, c.Date, a.Value, b.Alias
FROM (select Id, max(date) as Date from NAV group by Id) c
 inner join Nav a on a.ID = c.Id and a.date = c.date
 left join Portfolio b on b.id = a.id
ORDER BY c.ID, c.Date DESC, b.Alias, a.Value;
```